# On "Edit profile" page, Team selector dropdown cannot be selected if the current Team is frozen

Tags: bug, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams

When a Team is frozen, many functionalities cannot be performed. This also includes editing your own profile, where all input elements are disabled. However, the Team selector on the edit profile page is also disabled.

[image]

While disabling input fields may make sense since the "Save profile" button is also disabled, the Team selector is not related to the functionality and should be always available regardless of the current Team status. This affects all Team users since one of the options is always "Public Q&A".